# Better way to sync MySQL to SQLite

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, synchronization

I need to sync my MySQL database to android phone. I am new to this. So I am referring this [tutorial](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-remote-mysql-db-to-sqlite-on-android/) from Programmer Guru.

The Problem is in this tutorial they have used 3 classes, DBController, SampleBC.java, MyService.java. I have almost 10 tables to sync. So how can I change this to a better one?
Is there a way to sync the whole database?

I couldn't see correct tutorial for this.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what your app does, and how it uses the remote data.

I have written apps which have an 'update' feature - which basically serialises the whole mysql database as json, and then decodes it in to the sqlite database on the device.

Other apps will just fetch a smaller amount of data as and when they need it.

There is no better way per se. Just different options for different situations. You need to look at how frequently your mysql data will change, and what will the experience be for your app users. Nobody likes slow apps which spend 50% of their time displaying a progress dialog while they download data.

Comment: I will change the duration of syncing. But how can I use this code to sync multiple tables or the whole database?